# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error Code 0x8007000d IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am hosting my application at Server and I am facing this error. All configuration and setting already done at server. IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012 R2 and framework installed which is 4.0.30319.

I hosted this at my local system and it is working perfectly even tested at other system which have Windows 7 installed and the application is running perfectly.

Error Detail:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> ```
> Detailed Error Information:
> Module       IIS Web Core
> Notification     BeginRequest
> Handler      Not yet determined
> Error Code       0x8007000d
> Config Error     Configuration file is not well-formed XML
> Config File      \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AutoPartsPublishedCode\web.config
> Requested URL    http://localhost:80/ApplicationName/
> Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AutoPartsPublishedCode\
> Logon Method     Not yet determined
> Logon User       Not yet determined
> Config Source:
>
>    11:   <connectionStrings>
>    12:    <add name="AutoPartsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityRepository.AutoPartsEntity.csdl|res://*/EntityRepository.AutoPartsEntity.ssdl|res://*/EntityRepository.AutoPartsEntity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
> ```
>
> connection string="data source=ServerName;initial
>   catalog=AutoParts_latest;persist security info=True;user
>   id=sa;password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework""
>   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
>          13:
>
> More Information:
>   This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who face this error please change the web.config file the issue was with sqlserver sa user it was not able to access the application i change the web.config file with Integrated Security=True

I have two connection string 1st for Reporting and the other one for EntityFramework.

Hope anyother one who get the same error will resolve it by changing the connecting string web.config file

Regards